# How to run python script on a server?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

Well, I am a beginner in python programming language and a backend developer.
And I have written this python script using Telethon to auto-reply to my messages that are from the Telegram app.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
message = "Sorry, I'll be away until next week!"

api_id = 2******
api_hash = 'ffb5**********************'

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.is_private:
        await event.respond(message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is just a simple script and it has no practical help. I will change it later based on my interests.
When I run the script on my computer it is working as long as my computer is working. And I want to run that script always so that it can reply to messages even I am offline. And I think I need to run my code on some free servers.

**The question:**

Can you suggest to me some step by step tutorials or articles that fulfill my interests? (Consider that I am absolutely a beginner to server stuff.)

Comment: Use [`cron`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html).

Comment: You said `suggest to me some step by step tutorials or articles that fulfill my interests`, but **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more** is _explicitly_ disallowed on this site.

Comment: @MattDMo run a server with cron??

Comment: @Tibebes.M no. Assuming the server is *nix-based, use `cron` on the server to run the script, killing and rerunning it periodically.

Comment: Thanks to everyone . I will try reading about cron.

Comment: cron simply isn't designed for such applications (long-lasting, listening).. Also killing and restarting without any apparent reason is quite unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the process in background.
By running the following for instance (on unix based systems):

```
python <script_name> &
```

For a more robust solution that supports auto-restart upon failures, boot, etc.. consider [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

Here is an example command (using the PM2 route)

```
pm2 start <script> --interpreter=python
```